# How to use @ledgerhq/logs?

Tags: web3js, ledger-nano-s

Can someone provide an example on how to use the library ?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ledgerhq/logs

This is my code:

```
const LedgerWalletProvider = require('@ledgerhq/web3-subprovider');
const createLedgerSubprovider = LedgerWalletProvider.default;
const TransportNodeHid = require('@ledgerhq/hw-transport-node-hid').default;
const ProviderEngine = require('web3-provider-engine');
const RpcSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc');

const engine = new ProviderEngine();
const getTransport = () => TransportNodeHid.create();
const ledger = createLedgerSubprovider(getTransport, { askConfirm: true });
engine.addProvider(ledger);
engine.addProvider(new RpcSubprovider({ rpcUrl: process.env.BLOCKCHAIN_NODE_MAINNET }));
engine.start();

module.exports = engine;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const logger = require("@ledgerhq/logs");

logger.listen(log => console.log(log.type + ": " + log.message));
```